# Position floating div on top of another element

Tags: html, css, css-float, css-position, overlap

I have a header with a logo floating left and a phone number floating right. When the screen is not wide enough for both, the phone number jumps underneath the logo, which is not what I want.

Since most of the logo image is just background gradient anyway, I'd like to position the phone number on top of the logo element, when the screen is narrower than 818px.

How might I do that?

Here's the basic code:

```html
<div id="head-wrap">
    <a class="home-link" href="http://example.com">
        <img src="logo.png" class="logo">
    </a>
    <div class="tel">
        <a href="tel:555555555" class="phone">
            <p class="phone">
                <img src="phone-icon.png">555 555 555
            </p>
        </a>
    </div>
</div>
```

```css
.home-link {
  float:left;
}
.tel {
  float: right;
}
.logo {
  width: 657px;
}
```

Comment: Yes, I know that much. Could you perhaps help me with the code?

Answer (score 0):

First of all you can solve part of your problem by putting div.tel before your logo. This way it will be displayed on top of the logo if you don't have enough space. Then you could use a media query to put phone number on the left for example like this:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 818px) {
  .tel {
    float: left;
  }  
}
```

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/s2Lubqqp/1/

Comment: Tried it, but that completely disrupts my navbar menu underneath the `div.headwrap`.

Answer (score 0):

Since you need to overlap phone on logo you need to keep their position absolute and same position

also since you have set width of logo to  width: 657px;  better to make it auto when you resize window... hope it works for you

here is the media query :)

```
@media screen and (max-width: 818px) {
    .tel {
  width:auto;
  position:absolute;
  left:5px;
  top:5px;

}
.logo {
  width: auto;
  position:absolute;
  left:5px;
  top:5px;
}
}
```

Comment: While that does put the phone number on top of the logo, it also stops the phone number from floating right. Also, what exactly are you trying to accomplish with `left: 5px;` and `top: 5px;`?

Comment: @JeppeBech  just tryping to give 5px margin top and left thats it.. if you dont want that you can set it to 0

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like that :

```
.home-link {
  float:left;
}
.tel {
  float: right;
}
.logo {
  width: 657px;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 818px) {
  .home-link {
    width: 30%;
    max-width: 300px;
  }
  .logo {
    width: 100%;
  }
}
```

This way you can change the percentage width of the home-link section, and force the logo to fit it with the "width: 100%;"

[The fiddle is here](https://jsfiddle.net/hbtLgxrw/)

Comment: That just makes the logo smaller.

Comment: True, I think the approach to the issue is not quite right. The logo should not contain gradient but be a png and the background should be the gradient, so the logo could adapt its width without and without having to overlap on narrow screen.
But absolute positionning is your answer to your question.